# My website contains malware

Tags: web, malware, malware-detection

**Warning:** Something's Not Right Here!
www.mywebsite.com contains malware. Your computer might catch a virus if you visit this site.
Google has found malicious software may be installed onto your computer if you proceed. If you've visited this site in the past or you trust this site, it's possible that it has just recently been compromised by a hacker. You should not proceed, and perhaps try again tomorrow or go somewhere else.
We have already notified www.mywebsite.comthat we found malware on the site. For more about the problems found on www.mywebsite.com, visit the Google Safe Browsing diagnostic page.

If you understand that visiting this site may harm your computer, proceed anyway.

One of our website is now down and it looks like this. What is the cause of this? 
Please HELP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speculate what the cause is since you didn't provide the link, but my guess is that your site has been compromised. Look at your code and see if there is anything out of place. For example, a  tag that is below your closing  tag. Someone probably injected code on your site that contains data from their site. Google sees the domain that has been marked as malware and then says that your site has malware.

Can you provide a link to the code?

Comment: I believe it has to do with the link to www.cubepixelstudio.com which is also marked as malware.

Comment: @Stupefy101 You can remove the link. Also register for Google Webmaster Tools. It will provide more information about malware. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/malware?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Just contributing a few links that might be more useful for folks looking to troubleshoot this problem when it comes up on their server.

- [Malware Blog
  Post](http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/20071223.htm)
- [Stop
  Badware](http://www.stopbadware.org/home/badware)

Answer (score 0):

If the website has been compromised, run the antivirus software on your PC to scan the entire computer. If any malware is detected, delete it. Remember to keep antivirus program up-to-date. If security tools don't work, refer to the instructions below:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/243818/how_to_remove_malware_from_your_windows_pc.html
http://blog.mightyuninstaller.com/infected-by-trojandownloadervbsagent-el-steps-to-completely-remove-trojandownloadervbsagent-el/

Comment: This is not a valid answer.